# Tomcat CORS policy localhost

Tags: java, reactjs, spring, api, tomcat

Trying to run an old Java project on a Tomcat 8.5.
It's running and my Java API is working with Postman.

I'm trying to use this API with a React website. Both (my React website and my Java API on Tomcat) are running on localhost. But when I try to call from my React with :

```
static acquerirFemelles(femelles) {
    var myHeaders = new Headers();
    myHeaders.append("Accept", "application/json");
    myHeaders.append("Content-Type", "application/json");
    myHeaders.append("apikey", "sfj4-R5sdhffhs-fnhvSDFYT:DSRrfdj#fhqsm4zxwc-vhglxs15");

    let obj = [];
    femelles.forEach(femelle => {
        obj.push({
            "codePays": femelle.cheptel_pays,
            "numeroNational": femelle.numero_national.substring(2),
            "nom": femelle.bovin_nom
        })
    });
    var raw = JSON.stringify({
        "listeFemelles": obj
    });

    console.log(raw);

    var requestOptions = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: myHeaders,
        body: raw
    };

    fetch("http://127.0.0.1:8080/planningAccouplementWS/acquerirFemelles", requestOptions)
        .then(response => response.text())
        .then(result => console.log(result))
        .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
}
```

I got this error message.

> Access to fetch at
>   'http://127.0.0.1:8080/planningAccouplementWS/acquerirFemelles' from
>   origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy:
>   Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It
>   does not have HTTP ok status.

I already in my tomcat server put that (web.xml)

```
<filter>
  <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: J2EE does not run on Tomcat because it is merely a servlet container.

Comment: Yeah my bad edited the post, it's Java not J2E